# How to getElementById in java for android

Tags: java, android, html, getelementbyid

Here is what I'd like to do.

1. Read an html document into code
2. Use getElementById to get a certain portion of code by id, then save this string.
3. Create a text document to save this string to
4. Run the text document (going to be a html doc)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some html parser like it is Jsoup. Its easy simple and effective library. Down there you can see one my random implementation, I did for answering another question similar to this one. `.getElementById(id);` is the method you are looking for...

```
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class start extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
        Log.i("DOC", doc.toString().toString());
    Elements elementsHtml = doc.getElementById(id);
        for(Element element: elementsHtml)
        {
            Log.i("ELEMENTI",URLDecoder.decode(element.text(), HTTP.UTF_8));
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here you can get the Jsoup

http://jsoup.org/

For writing the file use `FileWriter` or any other class that allows you to write to file

Do not forget to add permision for connecting to internet in your `Manifest`

Comment: Hi another option would be HTMLCleaner, that was just to give you an option, but I too love jsoup which has a lot of less verbose methods similar to jquery (But if you do not know jquery they might be confusing at first).