# Displaying only a section of webpage through webview

Tags: android

I'm building my first ever app and it requires an activity to show a section of webpage inside webview. The webpage contains many adds and other irrelevant matter that I don't want my app to show.

for instance, I took youtube as an example webpage and tried to not show the body. I inspected youtube page and found "page-container" as id for central body part of webpage.

```
public class ResultsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);
    final WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.results_webview);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
             {
            webview.loadUrl("javascript:function() { " +
                    "document.getElementById('page-container')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                    "})()");
             }
         });
    webview.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com");
}
```

But the javascript code inside onPageFinished() function is not working. The complete youtube page is opening up in the app.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll have to check the id's manually by inspecting the web page. Once you get that, you can use the [jsoup html parser](https://jsoup.org/) mentioned in this similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810838/how-to-getelementbyid-in-java-for-android).

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
Elements elementsHtml = doc.getElementById(id);
for(Element element: elementsHtml)
{
   Log.i("ELEMENTI",URLDecoder.decode(element.text(), HTTP.UTF_8));
}
```